# What's the best approach to populate Pandas DataFrame NaN values according to other row values?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with some NaN values in all columns (Totally 3 columns). I want to populate the NaN values in each cell with the latest valid values in other rows with the fastest approach.
As an example if column A is NaN and column B is '123', I want to find the latest value in column A when the column B is '123' and populate the NaN value with that latest value.

I know it's easy to do this with a loop but I'm thinking regarding to the performance in a DataFrame with 25 mil records.
Any thought could help.

Comment: You may need to define how close is latest ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some sample dataframe, along with your expected output. Take a tour on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses for loop, but it loops over values of A where it is NaN.

```
A = The column containing NaNs
B = The column to be referenced

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Consider this dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,np.nan,6,7,8,np.nan,10],'B':['xxxx','b','xxxx','d','xxxx','f','yyyy','h','yyyy','j']})

     A      B
0   1.0    xxxx
1   2.0    b
2   3.0    xxxx
3   4.0    d
4   NaN    xxxx
5   6.0    f
6   7.0    yyyy
7   8.0    h
8   NaN    yyyy
9   10.0   j


for i in list(df.loc[np.isnan(df.A)].index):   #looping over indexes where A in NaN

    #dict with the keys as B and values as A
    #here the dict keys will be unique and latest entries of B, hence having latest corresponding A values
    dictionary = df.iloc[:i+1].dropna().set_index('B').to_dict()['A']

    df.iloc[i,0] = dictionary[df.iloc[i,1]]    #using the dict to change the value of A
```

This is how the df looks after executing the the code

```
         A      B
    0   1.0    xxxx
    1   2.0    b
    2   3.0    xxxx
    3   4.0    d
    4   3.0    xxxx
    5   6.0    f
    6   7.0    yyyy
    7   8.0    h
    8   7.0    yyyy
    9   10.0   j
```

Notice how at index = 4, A's values gets changed to 3.0 and not 1.0